# Remove php 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, php-5.6

I installed php on ubuntu 14.04 with nginx but the version installed was php 5.5.9. Since I wanted to upgrade it to php 5.6 I fired the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

I got a message stating that the ppa is depricated but however php 5.6 was installed and working fine only that it was showing as `PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)` I later went on and entered the command `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and `sudo apt-get install php5.6` which again installed php5.6 for me.

Now when I do: `php -v` I get `PHP 5.6.23-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli)` and when I do: `php5 -v` I get `PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)` How do I remove the deprecated one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get rid of the deprecated message, you need to use different ppa: repository.

You have to remove existing packages and the deprecated repository. Then, add the new repository and install the packages you need:

```
# Remove old ppa: and its packages
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 --remove --yes
sudo apt-get --purge remove php5-common
# Add the new ppa:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
# If you are using it with Apache, run:
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6
# If you are using it with Nginx, run:
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm
```

Subsequently, you have to make changes to web server configuration, since some paths have changed in the PHP-FPM configuration, etc.

More info [here](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/PPA-migration-to-ppa:ondrej-php).

Comment: The first command produced `add-apt-repository: error: no such option: --remove` for me so I used instead `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php` will install php7 if you are using `ubuntu 16.04`

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04 by default repository take to php5, So to install php5.6 in 14.04 need to add extra PPA (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php) and then type (apt-get update) then followed by ( apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-common )